# Class not found

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to write a front controller in PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('Controller/LoginController.php');
require_once('View/LoginView.php');
require_once('Model/UserModel.php');

class FrontController
{
    private $controller;
    private $view;

    public function __construct(Router $router, $routeName, $action = null)
    {
        $route = $router->getRoute($routeName);

        $modelName = $route->model;
        $controllerName = $route->controller;
        $viewName = $route->view;

        $model = new $modelName;
        $this->controller = new $controllerName($model);
        $this->view = new $viewName($routeName, $model);

        if (!empty($action)) $this->controller->{$action}();
    }

    public function output() {

        if (!empty($this->view))
        {
            return $this->view->output();
        }
    }

}
```

When I'm passing in a route object with properties as follows:

```
  route-> model = 'UserModel'
  route-> view = 'LoginView'
  route-> controller = 'LoginController'
```

PHP tells me that class `UserModel` can not be found.

However, if I replace the above with static expressions:

```
 $model = new UserModel();
 $this->controller = new LoginController();
 $this->view = new LoginView();
```

the code works just fine, which presumably tells me that the classes ARE available for use in my code.

I'm lost. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

Further inquiries with this piece of code

```
if (!class_exists("UserModel")) die("No UserModel");
```

tell me that the class doesn't exist. How is it possible then that I can construct it with `new UserModel()` and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think is should be `$model = new $modelName();` Add the parentheses

Comment: @mseifert: No, that's not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify namespaces for the class names that are stored in variables, since they are resolved at runtime:

```
$class = 'Your\Full\Namespace\Path\UserModel';
// ...
$object = new $class;
```

PHP can't reliably detect the namespace you implied for the dynamic class names.

Besides, it becomes more and more difficult to track the dependencies as the project grows. I recommend implementing an [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) system, or use an existing solution such as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can check

```
class_exists("UserModel");
```

if return false,
use below code get required class name, check it

```
get_declared_classes();
```

-- edit --

Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean

below code

```
route-> model = new 'UserModel';
route-> view = new 'LoginView';
route-> controller = new 'LoginController';
```

Comment: I did that already and it tells me that the class is not available. However, it is correctly included and available for use when I call it by its name.